# add sequential row number as first column to multiple pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas, I want to add a sequential number or a row number to different dataframes for example if I have the following dataframes

```
df1 
col1 col2 col3
123  aaaa   bbbb
345 eeee   cccc

df2

col1 col2 col3
1234  aaa   bbb
3456  eee   ccc 

df3

col1  col2 col3
12345  aa   ggb
34567  ee   jkc
```

I want to add a column at the beginning of each pandas so the output should look like this:

```
df1 
col0 col1 col2 col3
1     123  aaaa   bbbb
2     345 eeee   cccc

df2

col0  col1 col2 col3
3      1234  aaa   bbb
4      3456  eee   ccc 

df3

col0  col1  col2 col3
5     12345  aa   ggb
6     34567  ee   jkc
```

I manage to to this using an AWK command but after converting the dataframes to csv(s) how it can be done using Pandas only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am using `concat`, and try my best to keep all original information with all sub dfs (Even the original `index`)

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], keys = [1,2,3])
df.insert(loc = 0, column = 'col0', value = np.arange(len(df))+1 )
df1,df2,df3 = [x.reset_index(level = 0,drop = True) for _, x in df.groupby(level = 0)]
df1
Out[524]: 
   col0  col1  col2  col3
0     1   123  aaaa  bbbb
1     2   345  eeee  cccc
df2
Out[525]: 
   col0  col1 col2 col3
0     3  1234  aaa  bbb
1     4  3456  eee  ccc
df3
Out[526]: 
   col0   col1 col2 col3
0     5  12345   aa  ggb
1     6  34567   ee  jkc
```

Comment: simple, but great answer here! Small details like `keys` argument and list comprehension with `df1, df2, df3`